# ERROR 1075: Received a bytearray from the UDF. Cannot determine how to convert the bytearray to string

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm getting the following runtime error while running a pig script:

```
ERROR 1075: Received a bytearray from the UDF. 
Cannot determine how to convert the bytearray to string
```

Please help me diagnose.

Comment: Which UDF? What was the value? How are you using it in Pig?

Answer (score 0):

foreach A generate (chararray)com.stack.overflow.udf() as (a:chararray)